# Whitewashing files with a whitelist using multiple instances of awk from within a bash script , troubles

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I need to whitewash a set of files with a static whitelist, I am having problems because when I use the following commands on a small scale, they seem to work, however when I attempt to run them in parrallel from within a bash script, I am getting inconsistant results in my files. Not all entries are being removed as I intended, which means dirty data is still in my target files that need to be washed. I need a resolution, this is a life altering problem that must be solved, if anybody can give me a heads up it would be very much helpful.

(btw I split the whitelist into multiple copies hoping it would resolve the issue, it did not)

the file*s here are over 100,000 lines each of plain text domain names

Whitelist.txt is over 25,000 entries

```
 google.com
 1.google.net 
 websitetowhitelist.org 
 and so on...
```

example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Whitewash script washes blacklists against whitelist to remove domains that should never be blacklisted. 
#
#
echo 'Washing file1 blacklist with whitelist.txt ...'
cat 'file1.acl' | awk '{ m=0 ; while ((getline row < "whitelist.txt") == 1) { if (row == $0) { m=1 ; break } } ; close("whitelist.txt") ; if (m == 0) { print $0 }}' > 'file1.out' &
echo 'Washing file2 blacklist with whitelist.txt ...'
cat 'file2' | awk '{ m=0 ; while ((getline row < "whitelist.txt") == 1) { if (row == $0) { m=1 ; break } } ; close("whitelist.txt") ; if (m == 0) { print $0 }}' > 'file2.out' &
echo 'Washing file3 blacklist with whitelist.txt ...'
cat 'file3.acl' | awk '{ m=0 ; while ((getline row < "whitelist.txt") == 1) { if (row == $0) { m=1 ; break } } ; close("whitelist.txt") ; if (m == 0) { print $0 }}' > 'file3.out' &
```

Comment: Add file1.acl and your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

With files of this size, it is general a good idea to look at blocks in stead of single lines or, perhaps, try perl or another language.

So, another solution could be:

- tag the whitelist and dirtyfile
- sort them in order of the keys
- remove the duplicates

  ```
  sed 's/$/;a/' < whitelist > whitelisttagged
  sed 's/$/;b/' < dirtyfile > dirtyfiletagged
  cat whitelisttagged dirtyfiletagged > alltagged
  sort alltagged > allsorted
  cat allsorted | awk -F';' 'BEGIN {a=""} /;a$/{a=$1} /;b$/ { if ($1 != a) {print $1}}'
  ```

You will notice that the awk is a lot less complicated.

Comment: So, now I wonder what you are doing. Are you using the output of his process as input for the next try? Then of course nothing changes. The whitelist items have already been removed, therefore a new removal against the same whitelist will not remove anything.

Comment: No sir, it simply doesnt remove anything.